# rules working on 1.46 boost::spirit and stopped working on boost spirit 1.55

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

```
constant_double_quotation_string %= char_( '"' ) >> 
    *( spirit::qi::string( "\\\"" )[ _val += _1 ] | 
     ( char_ - '"' ) ) >> char_( '"' ); 

constant_single_quotation_string %= char_( '\'' ) >> 
    *( spirit::qi::string( "\\\'" )[ _val += _1 ] | 
     ( char_ - '\'' ) ) >> char_( '\'' );
```

now it is saying char is not a class or structure or union type with gcc 4.7.2?

Comment: please give more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Elaborating on my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31304912/85371)

In case you actually do want to expose the *unescaped* value, I'd suggest:

- not using `raw` (obviously, because we don't wish to mirror the exact input sequence in the presence of escaped characters)
- ***still*** not using semantic actions
- instead playing clever with `lit('\\')` to *match* the escape character without adding it to the output sequence.

Here I chose to use a single rule definition for both the double-/single quoted literal parsers. Instead, I pass in the expected quote character as an [*inherited attribute*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal._code__phrase_role__identifier___r1__phrase___code_______code__phrase_role__identifier__r10__phrase___code_):

```
qi::rule<It, std::string(char)> 
     q_literal;

q_literal = lit(_r1) >> *('\\' >> char_ | (char_ - lit(_r1))) >> lit(_r1);
start     = q_literal('"') | q_literal('\'');
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59be9e666d171d3c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct my_grammar : qi::grammar<It, std::string(), Skipper> {

    my_grammar() : my_grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start     = q_literal('"') | q_literal('\'');

        q_literal = lit(_r1) >> *('\\' >> char_ | (char_ - lit(_r1))) >> lit(_r1);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( (start)(q_literal) )
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> start;

    // drop skipper to make these rules implicitly 'lexeme'
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965
    qi::rule<It, std::string(char)> q_literal;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    my_grammar<It> g;

    for (std::string const& input : {
            "\"hello world\"",
            "\"hello \\\"world\\\"\"",
            "'bye world'",
            "'bye \"\\'world\\'\"'",
            "bogus" })
    {
        std::cout << "\n------- Parsing: " << input << '\n';
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        std::string result;
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, g, qi::space, result);

        if (ok)
            std::cout << "Parse success: " << result << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input '"  << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Printing the *unescaped* literals:

```
------- Parsing: "hello world"
Parse success: hello world

------- Parsing: "hello \"world\""
Parse success: hello "world"

------- Parsing: 'bye world'
Parse success: bye world

------- Parsing: 'bye "\'world\'"'
Parse success: bye "'world'"

------- Parsing: bogus
Parse failed
Remaining unparsed input 'bogus'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even specify the declared type of the `constant_single_quotation_string` rule.

Here's some observations and a working approach:

Since you

- apparently do not want the synthesized attribute value to be the input sequence *unescaped* you can simply use the `qi::raw[]` directive to mirror the input sequence directly. This way you can simplify the rule itself
- You don't need `%=` (auto rule assignment) or semantic actions (`[_val+=_1]`) at all; ¹

  Instead if you e.g. didn't want the opening/closing quotes as a part
  of the attribute, just replace `qi::char_('"')` with `qi::lit('"')` (or indeed, just `'"'`)

Simplified:

```
qi::rule<It, std::string()> 
    dq_literal,
    sq_literal;

dq_literal = raw [ '"' >> *("\\\"" | ~char_('"')) >> '"' ]; 
sq_literal = raw [ "'" >> *("\\'"  | ~char_("'")) >> "'" ];
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d57cbda5adfe3a05)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct my_grammar : qi::grammar<It, std::string(), Skipper> {

    my_grammar() : my_grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start = dq_literal 
              | sq_literal;

        dq_literal = raw [ '"' >> *("\\\"" | ~char_('"')) >> '"' ]; 
        sq_literal = raw [ "'" >> *("\\'"  | ~char_("'")) >> "'" ]; 

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)(dq_literal)(sq_literal)
            )
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> start;

    // drop skipper to make these rules implicitly 'lexeme'
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> 
        dq_literal,
        sq_literal;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    my_grammar<It> g;

    for (std::string const& input : {
            "\"hello world\"",
            "\"hello \\\"world\\\"\"",
            "'bye world'",
            "'bye \"\\'world\\'\"'",
            "bogus" })
    {
        std::cout << "\n------- Parsing: " << input << '\n';
        It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        std::string result;
        bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, g, qi::space, result);

        if (ok)
            std::cout << "Parse success: " << result << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input '"  << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
------- Parsing: "hello world"
Parse success: "hello world"

------- Parsing: "hello \"world\""
Parse success: "hello \"world\""

------- Parsing: 'bye world'
Parse success: 'bye world'

------- Parsing: 'bye "\'world\'"'
Parse success: 'bye "\'world\'"'

------- Parsing: bogus
Parse failed
Remaining unparsed input 'bogus'
```

---

¹ see also [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)